# How to implement on Keras YOLOv3 decode outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, yolo

I'm trying to train a YOLOv3 model using Keras (and this git as a reference: https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3) and my own dataset.

Even though, I've achieved good results in the training part, when I do inference of my model it runs at nearly 15 fps. Using other implementations in, for example, TF-Slim It has run at 30 fps (GTX 1070 used).

While doing some testing I've discovered that the bottleneck is because the Keras model outputs the 3 feature maps of layers 82, 94 and 106 and the decode part to obtain the bounding boxes and scores is done using numpy on CPU.

The model that achieved 30 fps was the one of https://github.com/YunYang1994/tensorflow-yolov3. The difference between these two models is that when YunYang freezes the model makes use of a predict method in YOLO's class.

I want to perform these same operations inside my Keras model, so I've thought of using a Lambda layer or create a custom layer. However, I don't know if it will be possible.

```py
...
    x = _conv_block(x, [{'filter': 128, 'kernel': 1, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True, 'leaky': True,   'layer_idx': 96}], skip=False)
    x = UpSampling2D(2)(x)
    x = concatenate([x, skip_36])

    # Layer 99 => 106
    yolo_106 = _conv_block(x, [{'filter': 128, 'kernel': 1, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 99},
                               {'filter': 256, 'kernel': 3, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 100},
                               {'filter': 128, 'kernel': 1, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 101},
                               {'filter': 256, 'kernel': 3, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 102},
                               {'filter': 128, 'kernel': 1, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 103},
                               {'filter': 256, 'kernel': 3, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': True,  'leaky': True,  'layer_idx': 104},
                               {'filter': 255, 'kernel': 1, 'stride': 1, 'bnorm': False, 'leaky': False, 'layer_idx': 105}], skip=False)

    boxes = Lambda(decode_feature_maps, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([[yolo_82, yolo_94, yolo_106], anchors, 0.5]) 

    model = Model(input_image, [boxes])
```

Would it be possible to add to the model this extra layer? Another option I've thought is to convert the model that outputs the three feature maps to .pb, then run a tf.sess and do there the method to get the bounding boxes and scores. Finally, I would freeze this new model. Although, I'm not sure if this one is even a worst idea...

Thanks!